# How do I position the following in MainActivity.cs?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

[image]
[Link to full size image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGfAP.png)

The above link is a screenshot of the code.

This my code on Xamarin. I tried rearranging it multiple times. It is giving me quite a lot of errors now. I tried changing position of the ; and }too.

I am using the HelloWorld program.

The source is this page

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/hello,android/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first error says that you do not have an id in your layout files of CallButton. To fix this open your Main.axml layout file and look for your button and give it the id of CallButton. It should look like this:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/CallButton"
    ...
```

Than rebuild the solution.

The second error is easy to fix. Just move you line 46 above line 28.

Answer (score 0):

For the first error, make sure there's a `Button` with the id value CallButton in the AXML.

To answer the the second 2 errors, move

```
string translatedNumber = string.Empty
```

*above*

```
callButton.Click +=
```